# Недетерменированный элемент в XSD схеме

Tags: xml, python, lxml, xsd

Требуется сделать проверку XML по XSD схема. Проверка производится с помощью языка программирования python 3.1, используя библиотеку lxml. При проверке появляется ошибка

> lxml.etree.XMLSchemaParseError: complex type 'piecewise.type': The content model is not determinist., line 193

XSD схема, на которую идет ссылка:

```
<xs:complexType name="piecewise.type">
  <xs:group ref="piecewise.content"/>
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="piecewise.attlist"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="piecewise" type="piecewise.type"/>
```

Как решить эту проблему?
Пробовал использовать утилиту xmllint на cygwin, валидация проходит успешно. На питоне все рушиться уже при подключении схемы:

```
from lxml import etree
schema= etree.parse("XML/imsqti_v2p1.xsd")
xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(schema)
```